# Parse JSON with an array in golang

Tags: json, parsing, go

I would like to retrieve all IDs and also the index value.

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "ID": "3b72"
    },
    {
      "ID": "d953b1"
    },
    {
      "ID": "8eac"
    },
    {
      "ID": "00b4c"
    },
    {
      "ID": "22360"
    }
  ],
  "index": 10
}
```

I tried the following but no success ( I am quite new in golang):

```
var result map[string]interface{}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &result)

ids:= result["results"].(map[string]interface{})

for key, value := range ids{
    fmt.Println(key, value.(string))
}
```

Comment: It's better to use a struct type.

Comment: @Sammy btw, please approve the correct and best answer, because it might be useful for others. They probably face similar problem and doesn't know how to solve it. see more https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Btw there is proably not the correct and best answer, this would imply that any other way would be false which isn't. Better also means readable and maintainable which obviously is better using structs instead of random type casts.

Comment: The question was *not* about unmarshalling JSON into a struct. Both answers are valid, but there might be a reason OP is using unmarshalling into a map - there's always a possibility that JSON structure is not fixed. That's why I voted for @xpare answer, which *exactly* answers the question without refactoring and assumptions. However, perfect answer would probably suggest an option of unmarshalling into a struct for convenience, and explain pros and cons of this approach.

Comment: @danopz btw, I was not trying to say that that my answer is the correct and the best one indeed. I'm just telling OP to approve the best answer from his perspective, and letting him know about the guidelines. because yesterday I saw his profile, I found out that he's rarely approve people answer on his own questions.

Comment: @danopz and also I use AND operator. "correct AND best". it'll not imply that any other answer would be false. it's very possible that all of the answers are correct, then OP decide one of them to be the best one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per your json string, few things need to be fixed. First, the `result["results"]` property need to be casted as `[]interface{}` because `results` hold an array data.

```
ids := result["results"].([]interface{})
```

Then, on each iteration of `ids`, variable `value` (whose type is `interface{}`) need to be casted into `map[string]interface{}`, so we will be able to access `ID` property to get it's value.

```
for index, value := range ids {
    valueMap := value.(map[string]interface{})
    fmt.Println(index, valueMap["ID"])
}
```

Working example: https://play.golang.org/p/Pxq6u7q-NAK

---

As per @Andrejs' answer, if your JSON structure is fixed, then it would be better to use well defined struct on the result (see @danopz's answer). [It has better performance](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/67jppg/performance_difference_for_unmarshaling_json/) and consume less effort interact with it's child.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably define a struct for the body and unmarshal into this:

```
var result struct {
    Results []struct{
        ID string `json:"ID"`
    } `json:"results"`
    Index int `json:"index"`
}

err := json.Unmarshal(body, &result)

if err != nil {
    // do something, result may be empty
    return
}

for i, result := range result.Results {
    fmt.Println(i, result.ID)
}
```

Then you would have access to the values e.g. by calling `result.Index` or `result.Results[0].ID`.

Working example: https://play.golang.org/p/j1WpEolQlXV